# How can I use JAVA/Python to separate delimiter text?

Tags: java, python

This topic has been discussed a lot but mine is more complicated. The delimiter in the text file is not just , or any single delimiter but two types of delimiter. "is the delimiter between different fields.

For example:

```
þIDþ"þNameþ"þAddressþ    
þ1þ"þtest1þ"þt"est1þ    
þ2þ"þt"est2þ"þtest2þ
```

I am going to read those lines, separate those elements and then store them into database.

The database table will be like:

```
ID   Name    Address
 1   test1   t"est1 
 2   t"est2   test2
```

Which is the best way to get this result? Split will not work. Pattern?

Comment: So your input has `þ` "quotes" around the columns, and the headers also have `¶` delimiters? Why don't the rows not have that delimiter?

Comment: sorry, I put it there but stackflow changed my original one. I do not know why so i changed ¶ to ". Thanks.

Comment: So you have `"` as the delimiter, and `þ` quotes. The Python `csv` module can handle that *directly*, just configure the quote and delimiter characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by using the `|` operator.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\sþ\\s|\\s¶\\s");
String next = scanner.next();
System.out.println(next);
System.out.println(scanner.next());
System.out.println(scanner.next());
```

Running this should output:

```
ID
Name
Address
```

Comment: Perfect! I will use this one since I use java a lot.Thanks so much

Comment: This'll fail to parse the delimiters inside the values correctly: `1þ"þtest1þ"þt"est1þ` will be parsed to `1`, `test1`, `t`, `est1`.

Answer (score 1):

You have data that has delimiters and quoting. The quoting allows the delimiter to also be used in the column values. Here the delimiter is the `"` character, and `þ` is the quote character.

The Python [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) can handle both directly; just set the `quotechar` and `delimiter` options:

```
import csv

with open(filename, 'r', newline='') as inputfile:
    reader = csv.reader(inputfile, delimiter='"', quotechar='þ')
    for row in reader:
        # handle the row
```

Demo:

```
>>> import csv
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> data = StringIO('''\
... þIDþ"þNameþ"þAddressþ
... þ1þ"þtest1þ"þt"est1þ
... þ2þ"þt"est2þ"þtest2þ
... ''')
>>> reader = csv.reader(data, delimiter='"', quotechar='þ')
>>> for row in reader:
...     print(row)
...
['ID', 'Name', 'Address']
['1', 'test1', 't"est1']
['2', 't"est2', 'test2']
```

Comment: That makes it so simple. I did not use python so much but i am starting. That is great. I will try. Thank you for providing the code.